# WPF how to duplicate a OpenFileDialog button and accompanying text field

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is a screenshot of a WPF app with the controls that i want to duplicate. Im having a difficult time googling what i want done, because im not sure of the terminology that describes the process. In the asp.net world, what i'd be after is a repeater control. All i want to do, is have a way that the user can click to add multiple files they want to stamp.

[Here is a screenshot with the control i want to repeat circled in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVjLx.png)

The browse button will be setup to push the file path to a `<list>` of strings, then later to a byte array as its being read in with `new PdfReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePaths[i]))`.

Here is the browse button code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create OpenFileDialog 
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
        dlg.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // set chosenFile variable
            this.chosenFile = dlg.FileName;
            inputBox.Text = chosenFile;

            paths.Add(this.chosenFile);

        }

    }
```

Here is the xaml of the text and button controls.

```
        <Button x:Name="getPdfButton" Content="Browse" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="421,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" Height="23" RenderTransformOrigin="0.408,0.407"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="inputBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="23,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="393" TextChanged="inputBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is, just described a requirement. What is the issue?

Comment: I thought i described the problem pretty accurately. ie. "Im having a difficult time googling what i want done, because im not sure of the terminology that describes the process. In the asp.net world, what i'd be after is a repeater control. All i want to do, is have a way that the user can click to add multiple files they want to stamp."

Comment: a repeater control, would allow the text field and button to be repeated and copied on a new line, so the user can browse to another file. That is what im wanting to achieve here. Im sure the textBox control will need to be dynamically named, hence, inputBox1, inputBox2, ect...for as many as they need to add.

Comment: @Dogbyte You're looking for an `ItemsControl`

Answer (score 1):

Use an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate containing the controls you want to be repeated.

Bind the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl to a ViewModel collection that will handle each file selection

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FileSelections}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FilePath}" Margin="2"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding BrowseFileCommand}" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In main ViewModel class:

```
public ObservableCollection<FileSelection> FileSelections { get; set; }
```

In FileSelection ViewModel class:

```
public string FilePath
{
    get
    {
        return _filePath;
    }
    set
    {
        _filePath = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("FilePath");
    }
}

public ICommand BrowseFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(BrowseFile);

public void BrowseFile()
{
        // Create OpenFileDialog 
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
        dlg.Filter = "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";

        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Get the selected file name and display in a TextBox 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // set chosenFile variable
            this.FilePath = dlg.FileName;
        }
}
```

You can fill in the gaps....

Comment: ok this might take me several days to digest. I dont understand a lot of what is going on here, so it may take me a while to make sense of this. like doing away with the Button_Click and if the xaml you gave is supposed to wrap my entire existing grid or only the elements i want inside the items control.

Comment: what part of this solution adds the repeatable new file path text box, and browse button?

Comment: The ItemsControl acts like a ListBox (except it doesn't support item selection, which you do not need). For each item added to the FileSelections collection, a new set of controls (as defined in the ItemTemplate) will be added to the list. Give it a try. See MVVM pattern guidance.

Comment: Ok, yes i plan to give this a shot, but im sure with my lack of complete understanding it will take lots of debugging for me until i can get it to work. There is probably some implied gaps here or there that im not seeing yet. i sure do appreciate your input.

Comment: The main thing I have not mentioned is that your ViewModel class will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the RaisePropertyChanged method. There is plenty of guidance on this online. Your UserControl will need the ViewModel set as the DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ListBox` control and when the user selects a file(s) add it to the `ListBox.Items`?